# Linked questions in right column doesn't ignore links that don't appear in the text in some cases

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, linked-questions

If you link to a question in the following manner:

```
[][1]
[1]: http://so.com/questions/13213
```

The linked portion will update, even though the links aren't shown in the post.

Questions included in the form of:

```
<!-- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60275 -->
```

Are also linked.

Comment: @Grace, I think it's a great plan.

Comment: Has it, @Grace?  Has it really?  Or was your _real_ plan to use this easily exposed plan as a __cover__, so that when it was revealed -- as it now has been -- we would all _think_ that your plan was revealed, when in fact you have an __even more secret__ plan that is STILL IN MOTION???

Comment: *"Don't worry, Natasha. Got fiendish plan for fiendish plan."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the link appears in the text, it will be linked -- it's irrelevant whether it is visible or not.

Comment: That's a fair explanation, I can't really see a good argument about why your dev team should spend any money 'fixing' this.